# auto layout modify multiplier of constraint programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints

How can I modify the multiplier of a constraint programmatically? I have set the following:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.5 constant:0.0]];
```

and I need to modify it to this:

```
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0]];
```

Comment: I don't think there is a way to change the multiplier, but you can just remove the constraint and set the new one.

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593641/can-i-change-multiplier-property-for-nslayoutconstraint

Comment: I ended up using the constant instead of the multiplier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others said, you have to delete the old one and add a new one. If you do not want to store it as a property, just set identifier and search to get it later

```
-(NSLayoutConstraint *)constraintWithIndientifer:(NSString *)identifer InView:(UIView *)view{
    NSLayoutConstraint * constraintToFind = nil;
    for (NSLayoutConstraint * constraint in view.constraints ) {
        if([constraint.identifier isEqualToString:identifer]){
            constraintToFind = constraint;
            break;
        }
    }
    return constraintToFind;
}
```

Then

```
NSLayoutConstraint * constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.yellowView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:0.5 constant:0.0];
constraint.identifier = @"1234";
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```

Then you can get this

```
NSLayoutConstraint * constraint = [self constraintWithIndientifer:@"1234" InView:self.view];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I ended up using the constant instead. to keep it simple...

`self.constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0 constant:(self.view.frame.size.width / 2)];
 [self.view addConstraint:_newsWidthConstraint];`

and then later I edited it to make it full width...

`self.constraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.width;`

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to change the multiplier because it is readonly. You would have to store a reference to the constraint. Then when you want  to change the multiplier you would remove the constraint and add a new one.

You could include a method like this in your view controllers implementation:

```
- (void)changeMultiplier:(NSLayoutConstraint **)constraint to:(CGFloat)newMultiplier{
    NSLayoutConstraint *newConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:(*constraint).firstItem attribute:(*constraint).firstAttribute relatedBy:(*constraint).relation toItem:(*constraint).secondItem attribute:(*constraint).secondAttribute multiplier:newMultiplier constant:(*constraint).constant];
    [self.view removeConstraint:(*constraint)];
    [self.view addConstraint:newConstraint];
    *constraint = newConstraint;
}
```

**Related Questions:**

[Can i change multiplier property for NSLayoutConstraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593641/can-i-change-multiplier-property-for-nslayoutconstraint)

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe that question didn't come up in my searches. Maybe I just glossed over it.

Comment: How do I pass in the constraint? This would make this answer clearer for implementation

Answer (score 4):

For modifying multiplier I use switching between constraints method.
You must Create constraints with different priorities else it will break the layout.

## Objective C

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint1, *constraint2;

// switch between constraints

constraint1.active = NO; 
constraint2.active = YES;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

## Swift 2.0

```
self.constraint1.active = true
self.constraint2.active = false
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 2):

There's an easier way to modify the multiplier of a constraint programmatically using [Layout Anchors](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html):

```
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0/2.0).isActive = true
```

Here's how it works:

[image: Result view]

Comment: This worked fine for me easily. I think the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, no extensions required. I tried for my case, worked fine for me.

So as multiplier is a get only property, we can simply set multiplier in the following way :

```
yourConstraintOutlet.setValue(yourDesiredMultiplierValue, forKey: "multiplier")

yourConstraintOutlet.setValue(0.75, forKey: "multiplier")
```

No extensions required and no need to multiply by superview height/width.