# Change relation of NSLayoutConstraint programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UITextView` at the bottom of screen.
It has `leading, trailing bottom space constraints to the superview`.
It has also `height constraint with value (constant) 40`.

I want to make this text view of flexible height as I go on typing more text in it.
I can make flexible height by changing height constraint value to `greater than or equal` to as:

[image]

It works fine and text view height goes on increasing.

But when I make it, storyboard show this error:

[image]

I want to make constraint value greater than or equal to programmatically, not from storyboard.

I know that there is one property of `NSLayoutConstraint` called

```
public var relation: NSLayoutRelation { get }
```

but as we can see it is readonly.

How can I change this relation to one of:

```
public enum NSLayoutRelation : Int {   
    case LessThanOrEqual
    case Equal
    case GreaterThanOrEqual
}
```

Or is there any workaround make a view of flexible height in auto-layout based storyboard?

---

I know about making IBOutlet of constraint and changing it’s constant value, but in my situation I can not do this, it should be changed dynamically.

Comment: This blog post might help you to understand how it works: http://devetc.org/code/2014/07/07/auto-layout-and-views-that-wrap.html

Answer (score 1):

Related to: [auto layout modify multiplier of constriaint programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722213/auto-layout-modify-multiplier-of-constriaint-programmatically)

With ARC:

```
- (void)changeConstraintRelationToEqual:(NSLayoutConstraint * __strong *)constraint{
    NSLayoutConstraint *newConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:(*constraint).firstItem attribute:(*constraint).firstAttribute relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:(*constraint).secondItem attribute:(*constraint).secondAttribute multiplier:(*constraint).multiplier constant:(*constraint).constant];
    [self.view removeConstraint:(*constraint)];
    [self.view addConstraint:newConstraint];
    *constraint = newConstraint;
}
```

Comment: How do I pass the constraint?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this in the past by marking the constraint I need to set at run time as "Placeholder - remove at build time" in Interface builder and then supplying a constraint based on the dynamic value programmatically by adding the constraint via code.