# tableviewcell using AutoLayout update constraint programmatically

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, uitableview

I have a custom tableviewcell using Autolayout, design in xib file.

design:

[image]

CustomTableViewCell.h:

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *customView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraintRatio;`

it's works fine in the tableview.

what I want to do is update CustomView's Ratio programmatically, before the tableviewcell display.

`-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    CustomTableViewCell *customCell = [self.mainTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customCell"];
        customCell.constraintRatio.constant = 2;
        [customCell setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [customCell setNeedsLayout];
        [customCell layoutIfNeeded];
        return customCell;
}`

but the cell's ratio remain 1 after that.
what did i do wrong or what did i miss? thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.

I misuse `customCell.constraintRatio.constant`. which should be multiplier.

but `multiplier` is readonly. so the only way to do my work is *delete the constraint and add new one*

after doing so, all works fine.

reference:
[auto layout modify multiplier of constriaint programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30722213/auto-layout-modify-multiplier-of-constriaint-programmatically)