# Deactive NSLayoutConstraint iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, nslayoutconstraint

I'm developing an app with a target of iOS7, and I get the following error when I deploy the app to an iPhone 4.

```
[NSLayoutConstraint setActive:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I looked into this and it turns out that `setActive` was introduced in iOS8. Question is, what is the alternative to `setActive` for constraints, circa iOS7? I need to manipulate the constraints programmatically and can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this would be to add/remove the constraint from the view:

`[myView addConstraint:constraint];`

`[myView removeConstraint:constraint];`

This has been available since iOS 6.0. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addConstraint: