# Need to change multiplier of NSLayoutConstraint according to device orientation: where to do it?

Tags: ios, rotation, autolayout, orientation, nslayoutconstraint

As `multiplier` seems to be a readonly property, I've read in some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593641/can-i-change-multiplier-property-for-nslayoutconstraint) that it is necessary to remove the old `NSLayoutConstraint` and replace it with a new one with the new multiplier you want. But I don't know which method(s) is(are) the correct to do this...

Thanks for your help

Comment: [`NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/activateConstraints:) and [`NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLayoutConstraint/activateConstraints:) are what you should be looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can catch the orientation changes by overriding the method `willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator`: in view controller, and then can update the constraints accordingly. And yes as you have mentioned if you need to change multiplier then you will first have to remove the constraint and then apply it again. If you know at compile time what multiplier you would be using in both orientations then i would suggest to use interface builder to create separate constraints with different multipliers for distinct size classes.

**Useful Material**

[Adaptive and Size Changes Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheAdaptiveModel.html)

Comment: Thanks, what is the difference between `willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator:` and `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:` methods?

Comment: viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator will tell you change in orientation in terms of size means for iphone 4 inch in landscape has size 320 * 568 so if orientation changes to landscape the above method will tell new size as 568 * 320. where as for willTransitionToTraitCollection:withTransitionCoordinator it tell the change in terms of size class not the actual physical size of the device

Comment: I'm not using size classes so... should I use the `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator` method instead?

Comment: yes if you need more control, alternatively you could use the method described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666269/ios8-swift-how-to-detect-orientation-change