# Programmatically Change multiplier of Alignment Constraint of Center X / Y

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

How can I programmatically change the multiplier in the simplest way?

[image]

For Swift 2.0

Comment: multiplier is readonly, for animations and programatic adjustments on constraints at runtime, playing with constant is advised as i know.

Comment: did you try solutions from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593641/can-i-change-multiplier-property-for-nslayoutconstraint ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So for Y, if you set the top of the image equal with a constant of 0 to the top of the superView. then enter this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var topc: NSLayoutConstraint!


let heightOfSuperview = self.view.bounds.height
topc.constant = heightOfSuperview * 0.90 // this has the same effect as multiplier
```

This is equivalent of Center.y multiplier = 0.9:1

Comment: You are the best! I was trying to broke the wall with my head and you give me the pill to the headache :)

Comment: Except this doesn't work since it is **constant**, as the accessor suggests. If you resize a view this measurement won't adjust proportionally, like a `multiplier` does.

Answer (score 2):

I try to use extension but it not work, but change to the global utility function and it work for me:

```
public class func changeMultiplier(constraint: NSLayoutConstraint, multiplier: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
    let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: constraint.firstItem,
        attribute: constraint.firstAttribute,
        relatedBy: constraint.relation,
        toItem: constraint.secondItem,
        attribute: constraint.secondAttribute,
        multiplier: multiplier,
        constant: constraint.constant)

    newConstraint.priority = constraint.priority
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints([constraint])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([newConstraint])
    return newConstraint
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, no extensions required. I tried for my case, worked fine for me.

So as multiplier is a get only property, we can simply set multiplier in the following way :

```
yourConstraintOutlet.setValue(yourDesiredMultiplierValue, forKey: "multiplier")

yourConstraintOutlet.setValue(0.75, forKey: "multiplier")
```

No need to write extensions or multiply by height of superview.

Comment: This is no working after the constraint has become active

Comment: you have to write yourConstraintOutletName.setValue(yourMultiplierValue, forKey: "multiplier")

Comment: libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to change the multiplier after a constraint has been added to a view'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException