# How to programmatically add constraint center with multiplier

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I do use multiplier with center constraints in the storyboard, now I want to do the same programmatically but can't figure out how to.

No, [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912068/programmatically-change-multiplier-of-alignment-constraint-of-center-x-y) does not help since the accepted answer is a workaround that would not auto resize if the superview size happens to change later on.

The storyboard center X constraint:

[image]

What I've tried without success:

```swift
// Does not exist
buttonLeft.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActivate = true

// error shown:
// Cannot convert value of type 'NSLayoutXAxisAnchor' to expected argument type 'NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute'
let newConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: centerXAnchor, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: buttonLeft, attribute: centerXAnchor, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
```

---

Is it possible?

- Yes: how?
- No: do you have any explaination of why wouldn't it be possible programmatically? Does this thing is a syntaxic sugar hidding something more complexe? I'm lost..

And yep, it works as expected when this constraint is set using the storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's possible, I missused the `centerXAnchor` instead of using `.centerX`

Also the order in which I called each item was not correct:

```swift
// Not Working
NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: centerXAnchor, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: buttonLeft, attribute: centerXAnchor, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)

// Working
NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonLeft, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
```

Though I could not find any way to create the constraint using the anchors methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false before adding the constraints programmatically.

Comment: Thank you for passing by! I'm already doing this in the code indeed , the question is more about finding the right constraint rather than fixing a non working constraint. For short answers like this one, you might prefer using the comment section, also to improve quality of your posts/comments you might want to often use `code syntax` style and other layout text modifications