# iOS - Change the multiplier of constraint by Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How to change the multiplier of a constraint by using Swift.

```
someConstraint.multiplier = 0.6 // error: 'multiplier' is get-only property
```

I would like to know how to change the multiplier in code (Swift).

Comment: create multiple constrains with the different multipliers and activate / deactivate the right ones at the right time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593641/can-i-change-multiplier-property-for-nslayoutconstraint

Comment: You can do like this:
someConstraint.constant *= 0.6

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Since `multiplier` is a read-only property and you can't change it, you need to replace the constraint with its modified clone.

You can use an extension to do it, like this:

**Swift 4/5**:

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    func constraintWithMultiplier(_ multiplier: CGFloat) -> NSLayoutConstraint {
        return NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.firstItem!, attribute: self.firstAttribute, relatedBy: self.relation, toItem: self.secondItem, attribute: self.secondAttribute, multiplier: multiplier, constant: self.constant)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let newConstraint = constraintToChange.constraintWithMultiplier(0.75)
view.removeConstraint(constraintToChange)
view.addConstraint(newConstraint)
view.layoutIfNeeded()
constraintToChange = newConstraint
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I try to do your code. But I can't achieve what I want, because of `self.view!`. I fixed `self.view!` in my case. But I use Mr. Andrew Schreiber's way in  existing "Can i change multiplier property for NSLayoutConstraint?" It did works well. I needed to search for it more.

Comment: How are you compiling when you are placing a logical statement as an argument? `addConstraint(self.constraintToChange = newConstraint)`?

Comment: `self.constraintToChange = newConstraint` doesn't compile, the whole example doesn't work

Comment: crashing the app in swift4.2

Comment: @Paresh.P I've updated the answer and it's fixed.

Comment: It is crashing - "'Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?  That's illegal."

Comment: Now working before iOS 12.

Comment: The example crash and does not work

Comment: In addition, for iOS 8 or later, it is better to use `constraint.isActive = true/false` instead of `removeConstraint` and `addConstraint` method.

The API says "When developing for iOS 8.0 or later, set the constraint’s isActive property to true instead of calling the addConstraint(_:) method directly. The isActive property automatically adds and removes the constraint from the correct view."

Comment: Short sweet and perfect solution.