# Swift 3 How to modify a multiplier constraint programatically

Tags: ios, swift

I have a multiplier constraint setup for a field label and the field value within a table cell. See attached screenshot. I want to conditionally modify the constraint based on the field label. So the field value will have more width as needed. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I'm using a switch statement to setup the field label and value. see below.

```
switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "Program: "
            cell.valueLabel.text = services.name
            cell.fieldLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 14.0)
            cell.fieldLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.valueLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 20.0)
            cell.valueLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 164.0/255.0, green: 45.0/255.0, blue: 9.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        case 1:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "Branch: "
            cell.valueLabel.text = services.branch
            cell.fieldLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 14.0)
            cell.fieldLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.valueLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 16.0)
            cell.valueLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        case 2:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "Phone: "
            cell.valueLabel.text = services.mainPhone
            cell.fieldLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 14.0)
            cell.fieldLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.valueLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 16.0)
            cell.valueLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        case 3:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "Locations: "
            cell.valueLabel.text = services.locations
            cell.fieldLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 14.0)
            cell.fieldLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.valueLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 16.0)
            cell.valueLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator


        case 4:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "Hours: "
            cell.valueLabel.text = services.hours
            cell.fieldLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 14.0)
            cell.fieldLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.valueLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 16.0)
            cell.valueLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        case 5:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = "Website: "
            cell.valueLabel.text = services.website
            cell.fieldLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 14.0)
            cell.fieldLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.valueLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 16.0)
            cell.valueLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        case 6:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = " "
            cell.valueLabel.text = services.longDesc
            cell.fieldLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 14.0)
            cell.fieldLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
            cell.valueLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 16.0)
            cell.valueLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        default:
            cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
            cell.valueLabel.text = ""
        }
```

[image: Screenshot of Interface Builder Constraint and Layout]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294522/ios-change-the-multiplier-of-constraint-by-swift

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to use this within a cell setup like mine. I'm still new at swift and iOS dev, so I'm sure it's me. Any help would be appreciated though. :)