# Change Aspect Ratio constraint value programmatically

Tags: swift, ios-autolayout

I'm using AutoLayout for my app designing. For one of my HeaderView, I had set it's height using AspectRatio.

Now when main view does not contain any data then HeaderView height should be 0 and when data is added it should be again set to the original aspect ratio.

Can we change the aspect ratio as we change the constant value of any constraint. I tried below code, but it's not working properly.

```
@IBOutlet weak var constOptions_Height: NSLayoutConstraint!
if arrData.count == 0 {
    constOptions_Height.constant = 0.0
}
else{
    constOptions_Height.constant = 50.0
}
```

Comment: i think you need to change the multiplier value not the constant.

    constOptions_Height.multiplier = cgfloatValue

Comment: @Rishabh Multiplier is a get only property.

Comment: then you could try to recreate that constraint in order to modify the multiplier, pretty much like we assign the frame to alter position of views. Or simply create that constraint from code instead of storyboard.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334017/how-to-set-aspect-ratio-constraint-programmatically-in-ios

Comment: also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37294522/ios-change-the-multiplier-of-constraint-by-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following approach

Give two constraints. One for aspect ratio and another for height.

Make the two active alternatively like

```
constOptions_Aspect.isActive = false
constOptions_Height.isActive = true
```

You can give height zero, in height constant.

Comment: Actually, you don't have to change `constOptions_Aspect` if it has lower priority than `constOptions_Height`. For exaple, if `constOptions_Aspect` has priority `999` and `constOptions_Height` has priority `1001`, then setting `constOptions_Height.isActive = true` will be enough.

Comment: Yes right. With different priorities also we can achieve the same.