# Animate NSLayoutConstraints multiplier and/or isActive state

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I want to animate a constraint changing for a custom view.

I've tried ways similar to this:

```
if widthConstraint.isActive {
     widthConstraint.isActive = false
     widthConstraintA.isActive = true
} else {
     widthConstraintA.isActive = false
     widthConstraint.isActive = true
}
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { 
        imageView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

the same for the multiplier (recreating a new constraint like here [Can i change multiplier property for NSLayoutConstraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19593641/can-i-change-multiplier-property-for-nslayoutconstraint/33003217#33003217) ). But all states change instantly.

Is there any method that helps to create smooth interpolated animation between two states?

Comment: Why change `.isActive` for *two* constraints? Why not simply change `.multiplier` for *one* constraint that is always active?

Comment: This is not possible to change a multiplier. This value has only a getter. When I recreate a new constraint I can animate the view. It changes instantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is suppose that a view1 in storyboard has a width constraint to the main view (self.view in code) like this

```
  view1Width = view * 0.7 + constant
```

instead of creating 2 constraints and switching between them by changing Active property ORRR [by deactivating current constraint with old multiplier and creating a new one with a new multiplier] leave it 1 constraint and play with it's constant

suppose i want to change view1 multiplier to be 0.9 instead of 0.7

I may do this

```
  self.view1Width.constant += self.view.frame.size.width * 0.2
```

same you do for subtraction

with this idea you haven't need to be stuck in how to animate active on/off but you still use

```
  self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: what is view1Width? NSLayoutConstraint? If yes, i think you have got a typo in the first expression `self.view1Width = CGFloat`

Comment: it's the width constraint of any view the you need multiplier with it

Comment: I don't mean use in code i suppose this setup in storyboard

Comment: If you got what I mean

Comment: And what happens when the user rotates their phone?