# How can I change the multiplier for single height constraints with two different multipliers

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard

I have image with some width, that related to superview with some percentage for portrait mode. When device orientation change to landscape mode how to change the percentage in storyboard by changing the multiplier value.

[image]

Comment: `Size classes` is what you need for this.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @ Web Artisan , I tried in Programatically. But i need in storyboard.

Comment: You cannot directly change the Multiplier, as it is "get only" - but a simple Extension provides a way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003217/6257435

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't change the multiplier, but you can add two constraints, one with the landscape multiplier and another for the portrait multiplier.

Then in code you can activate/deactivate the constraints when the rotation occurs.

If you get an error in the storyboard just set the priority of one of the constraint to 999 or something under the other.

Answer (score 0):

We can't the `multiplier` as it is `get only property`, but we can adjust width or height `constant` to match with `multiplier`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53043586/5519329